# How do you call functions from node_modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a ReactJS app and I'm using an npm package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-video-recorder) The package allows you to customize the UI, etc. as stated in the ReadMe (https://github.com/fbaiodias/react-video-recorder).

Within the node_modules package, there are functions like onStartRecording, onStopRecording, etc. If I use the default button that comes with the package, it can call onStartRecording, onStopRecording with no problems.

When I create my own record and stop buttons I have no clue how to get access to onStartRecording and onStopRecording. I would really like to use my own custom buttons because there is more that I want to do when I start or stop recording.

Here's a link to all the functions and actions from the npm package (https://github.com/fbaiodias/react-video-recorder/blob/master/src/defaults/render-actions.js)

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be extremely helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can have a base component for record library component and then have your custom button to import that base component and add more stuff to it.

Comment: I do have a base component that I created, and then I imported the video player component into the base component                                                                                   
`<VideoRecorder onStartRecording={startRecording} onStopRecording={stopRecording} />`

Comment: have you tried `()=> startRecording()`

Comment: maybe there is a use of `this` keyword in the library that needs to be binded

Comment: in the npm package there's a record button, when clicked, it runs onStartRecording so that the recording starts. In my React component, I import the <VideoRecorder /> from the npm package. Using my custom button, how would I call onStartRecording from outside node_modules?